# stanford nlp tool pos tagger property file arch parameter

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm using the left3words model provided by stanford nlp tool. in the props file, the arch parameter has indicated some directories which i am unable to locate. can anyone help on this? thanks alot.

arch = left3words,naacl2003unknowns,wordshapes(-1,1),distsim(/u/nlp/data/pos_tags_are_useless/egw4-reut.512.clusters,-1,1),distsimconjunction(/u/nlp/data/pos_tags_are_useless/egw4-reut.512.clusters,-1,1)

Comment: I don't expect many people on stackoverflow (other than Chris Manning) to be that familiar with the innards of Stanford tool. You might be better off emailing the authors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get those word clusters [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/egw4-reut.512.clusters).